# Laravel Route::controller() won't work on different URI's (PHP version 5.5, Laravel version 4.2.*)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

Goodevening all programmers!

A few days ago, I buyed a domain + hosting. I had made a local project with Laravel 4.2.x, and I wanted to switch it to my online-server. I noticed that I needed PHP version 5.5 for running this version of Laravel, so I changed this in my .htaccess file.

All seems to be correct now, but it isn't correct jet. De links (href) to other pages won't work! Every time I routed to a URL without the '/' URI, I got an error page wich says that the server can't find this document.

My files:

```
// routes.php

<?php

Route::controller('/', 'PageController');

//Route::get('/', 'PageController@getIndex');
//Route::get('/contact', 'PageController@getContact');
```

PageController.php

```
<?php

class PageController extends BaseController {

    protected $layout = 'master.master';



    public function getIndex() {

        return View::make('pages.index');

    }

    public function getContact() {

        return View::make('pages.contact');

    }

}
```

And my views: Everything is correct because it is possible to access the contact page at the '/' URI, but I just can't access pages at other URI's.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is fine, but routing is case sensitive. So http://example.com/Contact is not the same as http://example.com/contact

The first one (upper case C) should fail with a "Controller method not found" error. The second one (lowercase c) should work.

If it is not a case sensitivity issue, then your .htaccess file is not correct, missing, or unsupported on your web host. Here is an example of a know good .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thank you! It wasn't the case sensitive problem but it was the .htaccess file. Probably it was broken while transfering the local enviroment to the server.